# Show all objects in a NSTableView using NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

How to achieve a similar iTunes artists view like effect where all objects are concentrated in one row of a NSTableView just like this image:

[image]

So far I've achieved the same effect by adding an object named "all objects" and monitoring if the user has selected the first index of the table view, but it seems like poor practice since I'm even repeating the values inside the "all objects" index.

Is there an out of the box way of doing this or I should subclass NSArrayController? Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: "All Artists" is just one thing. It doesn't really magically contain all artists.

Comment: But in case of using a NSArrayController, how to change only this one thing?

Comment: The first thing in the array is the thing called "All Artists". It doesn't have to _do_ anything until the user taps it.

Comment: Suppose I have an array that goes "All Composers", "Beethoven", "Bach", "Mozart". Throw an array controller and a table view at it and you're done. Why is there a problem?

Comment: So there is no better way than adding an item named "All Objects" to the NSArrayController before displaying it (which I'm already doing)?

Comment: What could be "better"? I still don't see why there's a problem.

Comment: Given all the hidden functionality buried in IB, I understand the question, but no, there's not going to be a magical checkbox that does this for you.  Too many questions about what the arrayController should do if the user selects the "all" object and deletes it.  But if you want hierarchy, use an NSOutlineView and a Tree Controller.

Comment: I solved the hierarchy problem using a nssortdescriptor with an enumerator, but it feels weird

Answer (score 0):

I would try subclassing NSTableViewCell and dynamically add whatever content you want to that cell as you populate the table.

Comment: But that would not be an "out of the box" solution, I thought of extending NSTableView or NSArrayController, but that seemed overkill.